# Function that is called inside the trigger is not recognized

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create my first trigger in postgres but I keep receiving this: [42883] ERROR: function clear_article_flag  does not exist.
What I am trying to do is: when a new row is inserted on articles with a non 'automatic' author to set is_automatic flag to false for the specific id.

````
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_article_flag()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    update flags
    set is_automatic = false where id=  new.id;
    return NEW;
END ;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER maintain_dummy_flag
    AFTER INSERT
    ON articles
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.author not in ('automatic') )
EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_article_flag();```
````

Comment: The function's syntax isn't valid, so the function wasn't created - `new.id);` should be `new.id;`

Comment: 1) To be clear you want to set`is_automatic = false` on another table `flags` correct? 2) In `psql` what does `show search_path` return? 3) When you  run `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_article_flag ...` does it actually complete? I would expect a syntax error with `... where id=  new.id)`. Or is that just a copy/paste error? 4) In `psql` what happens if you do `\df clear_article_flag`?

Comment: I was a copy-paste error, no ) is after id=  new.id

Comment: And the answers to the other questions? Add the answers as update to your question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, but try adding the schema of the function: `CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema_name.clear_article_flag();`.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, being the first time when I've created a trigger and a sql function, I didn't know that first I should run the part that creates the function and then the trigger.

Comment: How else would the trigger: `... EXECUTE PROCEDURE clear_article_flag()`?

Comment: my thought was that clear_article_flag will be seen as the code in java sees the methods declared above. as I said, my mistake

Comment: If the script was run in the order you show in your question and the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_article_flag ...` successfully completed then yes that would apply. You are using code to create objects in the database, if the code does not complete then subsequent dependent objects fail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).